# Overwriting equals and hashcode results in wrong behaviour for removeAll()

Tags: java, collections, equals, hashcode

I have a custom object for which I want to define a custom test for equality. I followed the steps in [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) using the Apache Commons library.

However, the removeAll() method does not work properly when using it on two sets. contains() on a set does work however!

```
private String key;
private String rule;
private String component;
private String project;
private String message;
private TextRange textRange;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    HashCodeBuilder hashBuilder = new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31);
    hashBuilder.append(rule)
    .append(getRealComponentPath(component))
    .append(textRange.getEndLine())
    .append(textRange.getEndOffset())
    .append(textRange.getStartLine())
    .append(textRange.getStartOffset());
    return hashBuilder.hashCode();
}

@Override 
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Issue))
        return false;
    if (obj == this)
        return true;

    Issue rhs = (Issue) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder().
        append(rule, rhs.rule).
        append(getRealComponentPath(component), rhs.getRealComponentPath(component)).
        append(textRange.getEndLine(), rhs.textRange.getEndLine()).
        append(textRange.getEndOffset(), rhs.textRange.getEndOffset()).
        append(textRange.getStartLine(), rhs.textRange.getStartLine()).
        append(textRange.getStartOffset(), rhs.textRange.getStartOffset()).
        isEquals();
}
```

For clarity, this is the method used in the equals() and hashCode() methods. It simply cuts off a string given a certain regex.

```
// strips project key from component string, leaving only the path to the component
public String getRealComponentPath(String rawComponent) {
    return rawComponent.replaceAll(project + ":", "");
}
```

Expected behaviour (Debugging)

```
int i = 0;
    for (Issue issueA : issuesA) {
        for (Issue issueB: issuesB) {
            if (issueA.equals(issueB)) {
                result.add(issueA);
            }
            if (issuesA.contains(issueB)) {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

When printing i, I get 100 for sample sets A(size=100) and B(size=100), whereas `issuesA.removeAll(issuesB)  results in 0 issues being removed.

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Can you tell US which Problem you see with removeAll?

Comment: Can you please post expected result and actual result ? Possibly with the collections ?

Comment: Should `append(getRealComponentPath(component), rhs.getRealComponentPath(component)).` be `append(getRealComponentPath(component), rhs.getRealComponentPath(rhs.component)).`?

Comment: It was indeed a bug! Tnx! Issues after removeAll() changed from 100 to 40. There still seems to be an issue somewhere...

Comment: Also I was a bit misled by an api I was using which only shows x results per page. I used the first page from both datasets, but issues do not follow the same order among datasets. @Chris : you solved the bug and answered my question: thanks!